# .net, CSV Export TO Datatable, few columns value is blank

Tags: .net, csv, datatable

I have a problem, when I  want get some data from CSV file to Database, my setp as fllow:

1. I get this CSV file from special path
2. insert to a datatable
3. transfer data from datatable to database

now. when I access to no.2, i find 2 coulmns value is blank, who can help me??

Thanks

my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string _filePath, _fileName;
        _filePath = strFileName.Substring(0, strFileName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        _fileName = strFileName.Substring(strFileName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);

        string excelConnectionString;
        //string strFileName = @"D:\TestFile\Prelim\USG\aaa.xlsx";            
        //string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " + _filePath + @"\" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
        try
        {                
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + _filePath + @"\" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
        }
        catch
        {
            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + _filePath + @"\" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"";
        }

        try
        {
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;
            using (excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter apter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " + _fileName, excelConnection);

                apter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return dt;
```

Comment: It's only when you try to open the connection that your try/catch block might be useful.

Comment: hi, you menas that I don't use try/catch?

Comment: I mean the only reason why an exception would be thrown in your try block is because _filePath is null (which apparently it is not) or because of and exception like out of memory... not if the user does not have ace oledb 12 on his machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first step is to remove the noise. both try/catches are useless. the first one will never throw because you are simply concatenating strings. the second will provides no value it's the same as not catching at all.

i believe you want to use the name of the worksheet for the tablename, not the filename. and once the datatable is filled you then need to save those records to the database.

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""");
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1]";

    var table = new DataTable();
    using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         table.Load(reader);
         return table;
    }
}
```

then you can use this table to populate the database

```
var connectionString = "sql connection string";
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                   command.CommandText = "insert into table (columns...) values (@p1,...)";
                   //add parameters to command
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                } 
             }
             tx.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
           tx.RollBack();
           throw;
        }
    }
}
```